# Eloquent: relacionamentos entre tabelas de um blog

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.2

Alguém teria um exemplo prático de uso de relacionamentos no *Eloquent* da seguinte forma:

Tenho um blog com várias categorias, nessas categorias vou ter vários Posts, como eu faço para exibir uma categoria com vários Post na Views.

Já vi vários exemplos aqui, mas nenhum se encaixou no que eu quero acima.

Model Post:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag');

    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

Model Category:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

View index

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div id="home-slider">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="post feature-post">
      <div class="entry-header">
        <div class="entry-thumbnail">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('imgs/'.$post->image) }}" width="572" height="350" alt="" />{{--
          <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('public/imgs/'.$post->image) }}" width="572" height="350" alt="" />--}}</div>
        <div class="catagory world"><a href="#">{{ $post->category->name }}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="post-content">
        <h2 class="entry-title">
          <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/post-->
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
use Mail;
use Session;
use App\Category;

class PagesController extends Controller {

    public function getIndex() {

        $posts = category::find(1)->posts()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        return view('v1.index')->withPosts($posts);
        // $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();
        // $categorias = Category::find(1);
        // return view('v1.index')->withPosts($posts)->withCategorias($categorias);
    }


    public function getContact() {
        return view('v1.contato');
    }

    public function postContact(Request $request) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'min:3',
            'message' => 'min:10']);

        $data = array(
            'email' => $request->email,
            'subject' => $request->subject,
            'bodyMessage' => $request->message
            );

        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            $message->from($data['email']);
            $message->to('hello@devmarketer.io');
            $message->subject($data['subject']);
        });

        Session::flash('success', 'Your Email was Sent!');

        return redirect('/');
    }


}
laravel
```

Comment: Esse seu código tá funcionando? Os relacionamentos aparentemente estão corretos. Acho que depois do orderBy você precisa dar um ->get();

Comment: Eu estou querendo exibir na view os posts de apenas uma categoria...

Comment: E aparentemente você está fazendo corretamente: `$posts = Category::find(1)->posts()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`. tenta ai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos lá, o *Eloquent* possui uma maneira de listar todos os dados de outras tabelas relacionadas com determinada model.

Usando o método `hasMany();`, que você pode colocar na model, segue esse exemplo prático:

*Model:*

```
class Categoria extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'nome', 'descricao'];

    protected $table = 'categoria';

    public function retornaTodosOsPostsDessaCategoria()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

}
```

Certo, agora como você faz para acessar esse método? Simples, crie um objeto do tipo categoria, ou use diretamente a classe.

```
class CategoriaController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categoria = new Categoria();
    }

    public function listaTodosOsPostsNaViewIndex($idCategoria)
    {
        return view('categoria.index', [
            'categoria' =>  $this->categoria->find($idCategoria),
            'posts' => $this->categoria->find($idCategoria)->retornaTodosOsPostsDessaCategoria()
            //retornar esse posts é facultativo, pois voce tem acesso ao método na view;
        ]);
    }

}
```

Agora como manipular na view.

*View*

```
@extends('templates.app') 
@section('content')

<div class="ls-box">
  <table class="ls-table ls-table-striped ls-table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th style="text-align: center">Título</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($posts [pode usar tambem o $categoria->retornaTodosOsPostsDessaCategoria] as $post)
      <tr>
        <td class="ls-color-theme">{{$post->titulo}}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
@endsection
```

Pronto, esse método `retornaTodosOsPostsDessaCategoria()` retorna uma coleção de objetos, onde você pode manipular da maneira que quiser.

Comment: Obrigado @Felipe Paetzold